# JavaScript Infinity / ∞ back to a variable (To Infinity (to string) and back)

Tags: javascript, numbers, parseint, infinity, parsefloat

Consider this simple example

```
<div id="i">2</div>
```

script

```
var e = document.getElementById('i');
e.innerHTML = Infinity; // this produces "Infinity"
e.innerHTML = Infinity.toLocaleString('fullwide', {useGrouping:false}); // this "∞"
```

Now I would expect that if I do some of these:

```
var result = parseInt(e.innerHTML)
var result = parseFloat(e.innerHTML)
var result = Number.parseInt(e.innerHTML)
var result = Number.parseFloat(e.innerHTML)
var result = Number(e.innerHTML);
```

I would really get `Infinity` number (`result === Infinity` would result in `true`).

However it only works for "Infinity" and only with `Number()` and `(Number.)parseFloat()` for other cases it's **`NaN`**

Is there a *native* way how to parse "Infinity" and "∞" back to numbers?

*(something different than string comparison)*

Comment: I don't think there is. `parseInt`/`parseFloat` only returns a normal number or `NaN`. I am not aware of anything built-in that parses a string and returns `Infinity`. You may need to do custom parsing.

Comment: Wait, `parseFloat("Infinity")` should actually produce `Infinity`. Does it not?

Comment: `Number("Infinity")` also produces `Infinity`, but I think they're asking for something that can parse `"∞"` as well.

Comment: I've edited my Q => @VLAZ you are correct, I checked wrongly :) However Patrick Roberts is right - I want to parse both valid string representations back.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no such (built-in) thing as `Number.fromLocaleString`.